# Spring data default value of spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap-mode

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, default

After upgrading to spring 2.3.x my application didn't start anymore. After a lot of debugging I was able to determine the problem. The default value of the property `spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap-mode` is now `deferred`. My first question is why would someone make the default value of a property anything else than `default` and my second question is if I somehow can change the default value of that property without explicitly setting it in my `application.yml`.

Also found this piece in `spring-configuration-metadata.json`:

```
...
{
  "name": "spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap-mode",
  "type": "org.springframework.data.repository.config.BootstrapMode",
  "description": "Bootstrap mode for JPA repositories.",
  "defaultValue": "deferred"
},
...
```

Comment: "the --default-- value of that property without explicitly setting it in my application.yml" this is the EXACT PURPOSE of that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> change the --default-- value of that property without explicitly setting it in my application.yml

Well this is the exact purpose of that file - to override default settings that will become "new defaults" and can bu futher on customized via profile, envirnonment variables, cli arguments etc.

> why would someone make the default value of a property anything else than default

I can imagine that you have some sort of fail-fast logic around peristence layer, and in such case you would like it to be invoked right away - during app bootstrap -- , not after deployment when someone actually will use your application. Having it defferred is usually fine, and fits most of the usecases.